# Can a file name of a .vxproj be used as a variable within the file itself?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

My intention is to use the file-name as Projectname:

So I do have (for example) a vs project-file:
"MyAwesomeProject.vxproj"

And I would like to use it (for example) this way:
<ProjectName>$(ProjectFileName)</ProjectName>

$(Projectname) now would have the value "MyAwesomeProject"

Now I do know that "ProjectFileName" is a not existing variable, but is there an other variable that I can make this work with?

Comment: There is already a `$(ProjectName)`macro. Or did I miss your point?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, what I meant however was: Is it possible to use the projectfile-name as a variable. I found a solution which i will provide in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! I just had to dig a little bit deeper over here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/msbuild/msbuild-reserved-and-well-known-properties?view=vs-2015

$(MSBuildProjectName) is the variable that I needed. It is the file-name without the extension.